# ramda: set object based on the current state of the object

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I want to have a pipeline which will set up a location object. Suppose the location object looks as follows to start:

```
{
  pathname: '/users',
  search: 'sort=desc&sortBy=name',
  hash: '',
  state: {},
}
```

On step one of the pipeline, I want to set the `state.redirect` of this to be the current object, but without the `state` included. e.g.,

```
{
  pathname: '/users',
  search: 'sort=desc&sortBy=name',
  hash: '',
  state: {
    redirect: {
      pathname: '/users',
      search: 'sort=desc&sortBy=name',
      hash: '',
    }
  }
}
```

I started with the following, but it didn't really work.

`set(lensProp('state'), /* ??? */)`

what's the appropriate way to do this in ramda?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```js
const loc = {
  pathname: '/users',
  search: 'sort=desc&sortBy=name',
  hash: '',
  state: {},
}

console.log(R.dissoc('state', loc))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Ramda's **[What Function Should I Use?](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/wiki/What-Function-Should-I-Use%3F)** might help find functions like this.

Answer (score 0):

What about the following approach?

```js
const input = {
  pathname: '/users',
  search: 'sort=desc&sortBy=name',
  hash: '',
  state: {},
}

const { lensProp, set, over, dissoc, pipe } = R

// The W combinator to apply twice the same input to a binary function
// W :: (a -> a -> b) -> a -> c
const W = f => x => f (x) (x)

// stateLens :: a -> b
const stateLens = lensProp ('state')

// Note how W will apply the input twice: it'll set the input
// to 'state' property!
// setSelfState :: (Object -> Object -> Object) -> Object -> Object
const setSelfState = W (set (stateLens))

// dissocInnerState :: Object -> Object
const dissocInnerState = over (stateLens) (dissoc ('state'))

// setSelftState :: Object -> Object
const setSelfState_ = pipe (
  setSelfState,
  dissocInnerState
)

const output = setSelfState_ (input)

console.log (output)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```